# Why did the hurricane hit Atlantis?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

Fact:
There are six main requirements for tropical cyclogenesis:

1. sufficiently warm sea surface temperatures,
2. atmospheric instability,
3. high humidity in the lower to middle levels of the troposphere
4. enough Coriolis force to develop a low-pressure center
5. a preexisting low-level focus or disturbance
6. low vertical wind shear.

In the Stargate Atlantis 1x10 (The Storm) and 1x11 (The Eye) episodes, the hurricane passes over the mainland, so it is no longer met first point and should therefore be break apart.

Main question: why did the hurricane hit Atlantis?

Comment: All our knowledge of storms comes from Earth (and to a limited extent, other solar system planets).  An alien planet might have unforeseen conditions or long buried alien tech.

Comment: The "mainland" is relatively small on Lantea (15 million sq miles) compared to the rest of the planet (earth like gravity, so possibly earth sized). This leaves huge bodies of water (or rather one huge body) where the cyclone can pick up energy after leaving the mainland again before drifting to polar latitudes where it loses power. That and we never get told how much of the mainland it hit. Harvey passed partly over Suriname even causing a fatality there but still hit Houston with almost full force.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't remember if they mentioned how big the hurricane was. I think it was a "once-in-a-millenium" freak event or something, otherwise Atlantis would be able to withstand it.

Comment: @Adwaenyth Your comment should really be the answer. I was going to say exactly that. You get the +1 from me however by the law of "First!" I believe there was also a graphic during one of those episodes that showed the massive size of the storm...

Comment: At about the ten minute mark they mention the size of the storm in this clip. http://channelawesome.com/stargate-atlantis-the-storm-the-eye-sfdebris/